# How to set up ipdb context in setup.cfg or .ipdb?

Tags: python, ipdb

I am using python 3.71.rc1 on Windows 10 with ipdb version 0.13.2 and trying to setup default value for ipdb context in setup.cfg or .ipdb. What I did so far (without success) is:

- Created setup.cfg in project folder with single section ipdb and context value:

  ```
  [ipdb]
  context = 10
  ```
- Created .ipdb with same entry as above. No help.
- moved both files to my home directory but no help again.

I used recommendation from https://github.com/gotcha/ipdb where it is stated:

> It's possible to set up context using a .ipdb file on your home folder or setup.cfg on your project folder. You can also set your file location via env var $IPDB_CONFIG. Your environment variable has priority over the home configuration file, which in turn has priority over the setup config file.

Intention was to have initial context set to some value other than 3 when starting ipdb with:
    
`$python -m ipdb my_code_file.py`

Anyone managed to do it through config files?